# Rapidly adding int to vector and clearing causes access violation

Tags: c++, vector

This is some code that is designed to be run inside a .dll. If I remove either of my calls to *NumberSystem::AddZero* or *NumberSystem::Clear*, the code executes without crashing. I have been stuck for 5 hours. I am sure that something just went right over my head. Any help is appreciated!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

namespace NumberSystem
{
    std::vector<int> Numbers = {};

    void Clear()
    {
        Numbers.clear();
    }

    void AddZero()
    {
        NumberSystem::Numbers.push_back(0);
    }
};

void NumberThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        NumberSystem::AddZero();
        NumberSystem::Clear();
    }
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID pReserved)
{
    std::thread thMain(NumberThread);
    thMain.detach();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Callstack:

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001CA87EE5000.

memcpy_repmovs() Line 114   
std::_Copy_memmove<char const * const *,char const * *>(const char * const * _First=0x000001ca87ec5308, const char * const * _Last=0x000001ca87ec52f0, const char * * _Dest=0x000001ca8d9eef2c) Line 4366   C++
std::_Uninitialized_move<int *,std::allocator<int>>(int * const _First=0x000001ca87ec5308, int * const _Last=0x000001ca87ec52f0, int * _Dest=0x000001ca8d9eef2c, std::allocator<int> & _Al={...}) Line 1694 C++
std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>::_Umove_if_noexcept1(int * _First=0x000001ca87ec5308, int * _Last=0x000001ca87ec52f0, int * _Dest=0x000001ca8d9eef2c, std::integral_constant<bool,1> __formal={...}) Line 1593 C++
std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>::_Emplace_reallocate<int>(int * const _Whereptr=0x000001ca87ec5308, int && <_Val_0>=0x00000000) Line 757   C++
std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>::emplace_back<int>(int && <_Val_0>=0x00000000) Line 708    C++
std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>::push_back(int && _Val=0x00000000) Line 722    C++
NumberSystem::AddZero()
NumberThread()
```

Thanks again!

Comment: `DllMain` is called every time a new thread is created within the process, so this is likely the result of multiple threads mashing the same unsynchronized vector. Inspect `dwReason` and only spawn the thread on process attach.

Comment: @yurikilochek describes the problem. `vector` is not generally thread safe except in narrow circumstances, For instance you can preallocate a vector then access it from different threads and manipulate different non-thread safe objects in the vector (if their dependencies are thread safe) or the same object if the object is synchronized.

Comment: Try to replace the global variable with singleton: `std::vector<int>& GetInstance() { static std::vector<int> Numbers; return Numbers;}` and the also replace the caller side to use `GetInstance()`

Comment: The problem isn't the rapidity. The problem is that you are trying to access memory that has been deallocated by another thread. I recommend `std::shared_ptr` if you need thread safe access to an object. You will probably have to do some synchronization, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code reuses same `Numbers` variable from multiple threads.

I mean, `DllMain` callback is called multiple times with different `dwReason` parameter values.

You can prevent that with something like:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID pReserved)
{
    // Checks reason for being invoked.
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        std::thread thMain(NumberThread);
        thMain.detach();
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

> If you wonder how you could make it support multi-thread, then research about `std::mutex` usage for now (or ask different question).

Comment: Yep. Can't believe I overlooked this. I feel super silly. Thanks so much!